# Send parameters to another PHP file with image

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that takes two parameters come through a mobile application (*Text* and *Image*), to treat this data is used the following commands:

```
$image = file_get_contents("php://input");
$text = $_POST['Text'];
```

The next step is to send this data to another PHP file (**second.php**) via POST method, for this I try this code:

```
$params = array ('Text' => $text);
$query = http_build_query ($params);
$contextData = array ( 
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                'content'=> $query );

$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));
$result =  file_get_contents (
                  'second.php',  // page url
                  false,
                  $context);
```

However I need to send the image too, how can I do this?

> I need to send a image parameter in a way in which I can select it
>   from this command: `$_FILES['imageUser']` (which is located in
>   **second.php**)

Comment: What do you have in mind:  Write a local file and send its name to another program on the same computer?  Send the image data in a IPC stream?  Write the file to a the cloud and pass its name?

Comment: All the `POST` data is in `php://input`, so it will contain both the image and `$_POST['Text']`. So `$image = file_get_contents("php://input")` can't possibly work.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to do a file upload using `curl`. I don't think you can do it with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @Barmar, So this is a really a strange thing, I try a test, use php://input to create an image and $_POST['Text'] to create a txt file, the final result work, my txt file have the text inside $_POST['Text'] and image file have the image correctly..

Comment: @wallyk, I will try this format, but I will need to change some codes in my class inside called by second.php...

Comment: @Barmar Probably in my app, I call index.php?text=myText and in HTTPBody I insert my image...

Comment: If you use `?text=myText` then the text is in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: @Barmar, But why I can get the text with $_POST?

Comment: @Lacrifilm I have no idea. PHP also has `$_REQUEST`, which combines the `GET` and `POST` parameters, but I've never heard of a URL parameter being put into `$_POST`. Maybe your script is copying from `$_GET` to `$_POST` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the file to a temp location and POST the file's location+name to `second.php` file.

For example:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
// If you want unique name for each uploaded file, you can use date and time function and concatenate to the $target_file variable before the basename.
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
// Move the uploaded file
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
{
    // Now you can post the variable $image
    $image = $target_file
}
```

After you query on `second.php` you can even do `unlink($image);` to delete the file, so the moved images does not eat space on your server.